# Why pulling message have nothing google pubsub?

Tags: java, gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub

[image]

[image]
I have subscription `VIEW_TOPIC` with pull strategy. Why I cannot see any message although have 7 delay messages? I cannot figure out what am I missing. By the way, I'm running subscriber on k8s GCP. I was also add `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` variable environment.

Subscriber configuration

```java
    private Subscriber buildSubscriber() {

        try (SubscriptionAdminClient subscriptionAdminClient = SubscriptionAdminClient.create()) {
            TopicName topicName = TopicName.of(projectId, topic);
            ProjectSubscriptionName subscriptionName =
                    ProjectSubscriptionName.of(projectId, subscriptionId);
            // Create a pull subscription with default acknowledgement deadline of 10 seconds.
            // Messages not successfully acknowledged within 10 seconds will get resent by the server.
            Subscription subscription =
                    subscriptionAdminClient.createSubscription(
                            subscriptionName, topicName, PushConfig.getDefaultInstance(), 10);
            System.out.println("Created pull subscription: " + subscription.getName());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Cannot create pull subscription");
        } catch (AlreadyExistsException existsException) {
            LOGGER.warn("Subscription already created");
        }

        ProjectSubscriptionName subscriptionName = ProjectSubscriptionName.of(projectId, subscriptionId);
        LOGGER.info("Subscribe topic: " + topic + " | SubscriptionId: " + subscriptionId);
        // default is 4 * num of processor
        ExecutorProvider executorProvider = InstantiatingExecutorProvider.newBuilder().build();
        Subscriber.Builder subscriberBuilder = Subscriber.newBuilder(subscriptionName, new MessageReceiverImpl())
                .setExecutorProvider(executorProvider);
        // The subscriber will pause the message stream and stop receiving more messages from the
        // server if any one of the conditions is met.
        FlowControlSettings flowControlSettings =
            FlowControlSettings.newBuilder()
                .setMaxOutstandingElementCount(100)
                // the maximum size of messages the subscriber
                // receives before pausing the message stream.
                // 10Mib
                .setMaxOutstandingRequestBytes(10L * 1024L * 1024L)
                .build();
        subscriberBuilder.setFlowControlSettings(flowControlSettings);


        Subscriber subscriber = subscriberBuilder.build();
        subscriber.addListener(new ApiService.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void failed(ApiService.State from, Throwable failure) {
                LOGGER.error(from, failure);
            }
        }, MoreExecutors.directExecutor());
        return subscriber;
    }
```

Subscriber

```java
    public void startSubscribeMessage() {
        LOGGER.info("Begin subscribe topic " + topic);

        this.subscriber.startAsync().awaitRunning();

        LOGGER.info("Subscriber start successfully!!!");
    }
```

```java
public class MessageReceiverImpl implements MessageReceiver {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MessageReceiverImpl.class);
    private final LogSave logSave = MatchSave.getInstance();
    @Override
    public void receiveMessage(PubsubMessage message, AckReplyConsumer consumer) {
        ByteString data = message.getData();
        // Get the schema encoding type.
        String encoding = message.getAttributesMap().get("googclient_schemaencoding");
        Req.LogReq logReqMsg = null;
        try {
            switch (encoding) {
                case "BINARY":
                    logReqMsg = Req.LogReq.parseFrom(data);
                    break;
                case "JSON":
                    Req.LogReq.Builder msgBuilder = Req.LogReq.newBuilder();
                    JsonFormat.parser().merge(data.toStringUtf8(), msgBuilder);
                    logReqMsg = msgBuilder.build();
                    break;
            }
            LOGGER.info((JsonFormat.printer().omittingInsignificantWhitespace().print(logReqMsg)));
            logSave.addLogMsg(battleLogMsg);
        } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        consumer.ack();
    }
}
```

With `Req.LogReq` is a proto message. My dependency:

```
    // google cloud
    implementation platform('com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:22.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-pubsub'
    implementation group: 'com.google.protobuf', name: 'protobuf-java-util', version: '3.17.2'
```

And the call function `logSave.addLogMsg(battleLogMsg);` is add message to `CopyOnWriteArrayList`

Comment: Are you using [synchronous pull](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#synchronous_pull) or [asynchronous streaming pull via the client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#asynchronous-pull)?

Comment: I am using asynchronous pull.

Comment: Can you share the code where you connect to PubSub?

Comment: I've edited the post with the code where I connect to PubSub.

Comment: What is `MessageReceiverImpl`? can you add more details?

Comment: I've added `MessageReceiverImpl` implementation. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I'm curious about, what happen when the subscriber leave the subscription? Are they get rebalance like Kafka consumer?